# Shell scripting SQLite

Tags: sqlite, shell

How do I write a shell script that displays SQLite results? I have written a script that adds an entry to the SQLite database. Now I want to display the results after adding that entry.
Here's my script:

```
echo 'insert into myTable (Date, Details, Category, Average) values (datetime('\''now'\'','\''localtime'\''), '\'''$1''\'', '\'''$2''\'', '$3');'|sqlite3 /Users/user/Documents/Test/dbName.db
```

After this I want the script to echo/spit the output of statements:

```
select sum(Average) from (select * from myTable where Category = 'category1');
select sum(Average) from (select * from myTable where Category = 'category2');
```

The format should be like this:

```
Category1 total = <output of first statement>
Category2 total = <output of second statement>
```

Thats it. I am quite new to SQL and not that great with shell scripting. I am also looking for good tutorials explaining problems like this.

Comment: Since you are ' not that great with shell scripting' then you probably should not be using shell scripts to solve this problem.  Use whatever  coding system ( C++, TCL, python, ... ) you are most expert in.  Almost everything you might want to use has an available interface to the sqlite API.

Comment: @ravenspoint: Actually, I am managing my finances using SQL, and the shell scripts are used to quickly add stuff and read sums by running them from a script launcher (Quicksilver).

Comment: Since you say "I am quite new to SQL" I would recommend against using SQL to manage your finances!

Comment: Scripting languages (Perl, Python, Ruby, etc) are much better suited for the task.

Comment: @ravenspoint: I am learning SQL, and by managing my finances,  I mean just adding daily expenses and other stuff, nothing too complicated (just one table). I was looking for good apps for this, but there cannot be an app which is exactly what I want.

Comment: @JackManey: Shell is almost the only scripting language that I know something about. I rarely write scripts, I mostly work with compiled languages. If shell scripting won't work, the only doable option for me is to write a C program for this and then invoke it from my app launcher. work … work … ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One common way to solve this problem is to use a shell feature called a here document, try this:

```
 sqlite3 /Users/user/Documents/Test/dbName.dba <<EOS
     insert into myTable (Date, Details, Category, Average) 
               values(datetime('now','localtime'), '$1', '$2', '$3');

     select "Category1 total = " sum(Average) from (
          select * from myTable where Category = 'category1'
     );

     select "Category2 total = " sum(Average) from (
         select * from myTable where Category = 'category2'
     );

 EOS
```

Note that EOS can be any string you like (I think of EndOfScript), but it must be alone on the last line of text with no trailing whitespace.

As I don't use sqlite3, you may need some statment to close off the batch that I'm not aware of. Also, I'm not certain that the '$1' stuff will work, if sqlite3 is forgiving, try "$1", etc instead. Also, you may need to an a comma after the `"CategoryN total = "` string.

Note that this solution allows you to create your sql DML statements pretty much as big/long as you want. For stuff that will happen regularly and it ranging over large  tables, if you have permissions on our system, you may want your DML to a stored procedure and call that.

I hope this helps.

(If this doesn't work, please edit your post to indicate shell you are using, OS/Linux Ver and a minimal version of error messages that you are getting).

Comment: Thanks. The logic is perfect, but I cannot insert into the table (first SQL statement). The problem is regarding brackets/quotes. The other statements work properly. BTW, Rs.52 stuff is not in my question. I have a browser extension that converts dollars to rupees, so the Rs.52.. are actually dollar signs, i.e. the arguments: dollar1, dollar2, dollar3. Somehow, it is showing me dollar signs and others Rs.52

Comment: You can single-quote the first EOS, like so: `sqlite3 dbName.dba <<'EOS'`  That [prevents shell variables from being expanded](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) within the heredoc.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to assign sqlite SELECT result to a shell variable, you can do this.

```
r=$(sqlite3 your_db_path.db "select something from some_table where condition")
```

`$r` will be your variable.

Single row also can be fetched. You can do some work to split it into an array, may be using [IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator)

Additionally keep in mind to use `#!/bin/bash` convention on top of your every shell script. It'll solve many unwanted issues. Some times old `#!/bin/sh` convention gives troubles. :).

Comment: it would be very helpful if you could show how values can be fetched from $r