# bash update mysql from bash command

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I want to update database from bash command:

```
#!/bin/bash
list= cat /home/wwwroot/list.txt;
mysql -u root -D dbname -e "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = '$list' WHERE meta_key = 1";
```

cat /home/wwwroot/list.txt 
text1 
text2 
text3
...

How to $list variable can be read in sql query?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to provide more sample data so we understand exactly what you mean by "update database from cat command", but you may find my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649732/620097 to give you a place to start on working with SQL and shell scripting. Good luck.

Comment: If the file is on the same host where the MySQL Server is running, you can do this more easily and more securely with the [LOAD_FILE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) function.

Comment: `list=$(cat /home/wwwroot/list.txt)`

Comment: @Bill Karwin get result NULL.

Comment: @janos worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

`Cat` is an overkill here.

---

I suggest using an array if you need space delimited values.

```
list=($(</home/wwwroot/list.txt))
mysql -u root -D dbname -e "UPDATE wp_postmeta \
SET meta_value = '${list[@]}' WHERE meta_key = 1";
```

The advantage here is if you need comma separated values then you could employ bash [[ parameter substitution ]](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) to achieve your feet. Just change the query to

```
mysql -u root -D dbname -e "UPDATE wp_postmeta \
SET meta_value = '${list[@]/%/,}' WHERE meta_key = 1";
#Note ${list[@]/%/,} appends comma after each value in the text file
```

All good <kbd>:-)</kbd>