# Bash scripts & PLSQL Procedure

Tags: bash, oracle, variables, stored-procedures, while-loop

I've been trying to make it work for hours.. But I guess it's beyond my knowledge...

Here is my issue : I am trying to run a shell script, which first does an SQL request to gather some data into a $tmp var, then run a PL/SQL Procedure using the $tmp content.
The PL/SQL procedure must be called X time, where X is the number of row from the SQL request, best would be to have a single connection for every row from the SQL output.

So here is what I tried :

1 - SQL REQUEST : Store WANTED_DATA into $tmp var in order to reuse it later into the PL SQL Procedure.
For the example, lets say "WANTED_DATA" = "123, 321; 789, 987;" This part works fine but can be changed if required - as long as the result are stored into a var.

```
#!/bin/sh
function SQL_REQ {
    tmp=$(`$APP_SQL -S $USR/$PWD@$DB <<-eof
    select  WANTED_DATA
    from TABLE
    exit
    eof`)
    PLSQL_Proc #This call the second function
}
```

2 - PL SQL Procedure : And here is the tricky part. A function that will run a PL SQL Procedure using the "$tmp" from previous request into the PLSQL procedure. 
Another issue I have, is that even if this work, it will connect and disconnect from the database for each row (delimited by ";") of $tmp.

```
function PLSQL_Proc {
     while IFS=; read -r WANTED_DATA
     do
          $APP_SQL -S $USR/$PWD@$DB<<-eof
          DECLARE
               result varchar2(100);
          BEGIN
               result := scripts.remove_data("$WANTED_DATA");
          END;
          /
          eof
          done <<< "$tmp"
}
```

Current error(s) :

```
'123, 321' : Command not found - at line 12 (= line Done <<< "$tmp")

scripts.remove_data() : invalid number of arguments
```

N.B :

-Using Redhat (The before-last version - didnt took time to upgrade yet haha), and Oracle DB

If any of you have an idea, please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: This moment you realize you forgot to say "Hello" and that the edit wont agree to add it...

Comment: "Didn't use the auto-formatter because my code has back-tics in it".  Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to have proper formatting for `code/data/output/errMsgs` (including back-tics).. Can't you use `$( echo cmd-substitution, join the 1990s!)` ? Good luck.

Comment: And, sorry to say, but As is, without proper formatting your Q is unreadable.  Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649732/620097 will help you. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter : Ok improved formatting using { } - sorry I didnt knew about this. Is this more readable now ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok wasnt that hard in the end, could even be done in a single function :

```
   function PLSQL_Proc 
    {
         while IFS=; read -r WANTED_DATA
    #In case WANTED_DATA are multiple row, need to add a separator to 
    # read after -r option, like : -d';'
    #Then concatenate a ";" after WANTED_DATA, like :  WANTED_DATA||';'
         do
              $APP_SQL -S $USR/$PWD@$DB<<-eof
              DECLARE
                   result varchar2(100);
              BEGIN
                   result := scripts.remove_data("$WANTED_DATA");
              END;
              /
              eof

             done <<< `$APP_SQL -S $USR/$PWD@$DB <<-eof
                    select WANTED_DATA
                    from TABLE
                    exit
                    eof`
    }
```

Comment: Still the issue of multiple connection to DB in case of multirow to deal with.