# How we can update MIB variables values dynamically in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, snmp, net-snmp, mib

I have created one mib file where five variables are added. Also by using the following command

```
snmptranslate -m +GET-LATEST-SIGNALS-MIB -IR -On oversightInteger
```

I'm able to see the OID's of the all varialbes.

After this by using "PASS protocol" I tried to get the data from the one variable with the help of following script file

```js
#!/bin/sh -f

PLACE=".1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.1"
REQ="$2"    # Requested OID

#
#  Process SET requests by simply logging the assigned value
#      Note that such "assignments" are not persistent,
#      nor is the syntax or requested value validated
#
if [ "$1" = "-s" ]; then
  echo $* >> /tmp/passtest.log
  exit 0
fi

#
#  GETNEXT requests - determine next valid instance
#
if [ "$1" = "-n" ]; then
  case "$REQ" in
    $PLACE|             \
    $PLACE.0|           \
    $PLACE.0.*|         \
    $PLACE.1)       RET=$PLACE.1.0 ;;     # netSnmpPassString.0

    $PLACE.1.*|         \
    $PLACE.2|           \
    $PLACE.2.0|         \
    $PLACE.2.0.*|       \
    $PLACE.2.1|         \
    $PLACE.2.1.0|       \
    $PLACE.2.1.0.*|     \
    $PLACE.2.1.1|       \
    $PLACE.2.1.1.*|     \
    $PLACE.2.1.2|       \
    $PLACE.2.1.2.0) RET=$PLACE.2.1.2.1 ;; # netSnmpPassInteger.1

    $PLACE.2.1.2.*|     \
    $PLACE.2.1.3|       \
    $PLACE.2.1.3.0) RET=$PLACE.2.1.3.1 ;; # netSnmpPassOID.1

    $PLACE.2.*|         \
    $PLACE.3)       RET=$PLACE.3.0 ;;     # netSnmpPassTimeTicks.0
    $PLACE.3.*|         \
    $PLACE.4)       RET=$PLACE.4.0 ;;     # netSnmpPassIpAddress.0
    $PLACE.4.*|         \
    $PLACE.5)       RET=$PLACE.5.0 ;;     # netSnmpPassCounter.0
    $PLACE.5.*|         \
    $PLACE.6)       RET=$PLACE.6.0 ;;     # netSnmpPassGauge.0

    *)              exit 0 ;;
  esac
else
#
#  GET requests - check for valid instance
#
  case "$REQ" in
    $PLACE.1.0|         \
    $PLACE.2.1.2.1|     \
    $PLACE.2.1.3.1|     \
    $PLACE.3.0|         \
    $PLACE.4.0|         \
    $PLACE.5.0|         \
    $PLACE.6.0)     RET=$REQ ;;
    *)              exit 0 ;;
  esac
fi

#
#  "Process" GET* requests - return hard-coded value
#
echo "$RET"
case "$RET" in
  $PLACE.1.0)     echo "string";    echo "Life, the Universe, and Everything"; exit 0 ;;
  $PLACE.2.1.2.1) echo "integer";   echo "42";                                 exit 0 ;;
  $PLACE.2.1.3.1) echo "objectid";  echo "$PLACE.99";                          exit 0 ;;
  $PLACE.3.0)     echo "timeticks"; echo "363136200";                          exit 0 ;;
  $PLACE.4.0)     echo "ipaddress"; echo "127.0.0.1";                          exit 0 ;;
  $PLACE.5.0)     echo "counter";   echo "42";                                 exit 0 ;;
  $PLACE.6.0)     echo "gauge";     echo "42";                                 exit 0 ;;
  *)              echo "string";    echo "ack... $RET $REQ";                   exit 0 ;;  # Should not happen
esac
```

After running the above script file I used the following command

```
snmpwalk -v2c localhost -c public .1.3.6.1.4.1.53864
```

and the output i got as follows

```
GET-LATEST-SIGNALS-MIB::oversightInteger.1.0 = STRING: "Life, the 
Universe, and Everything"
GET-LATEST-SIGNALS-MIB::oversightInteger.2.1.2.1 = Wrong Type 
(should be OCTET STRING): INTEGER: 42
GET-LATEST-SIGNALS-MIB::oversightInteger.2.1.3.1 = Wrong Type 
(should be OCTET STRING): OID: GET-LATEST-SIGNALS- 
MIB::oversightInteger.99
GET-LATEST-SIGNALS-MIB::oversightInteger.3.0 = Wrong Type (should 
be OCTET STRING): Timeticks: (363136200) 42 days, 0:42:42.00
GET-LATEST-SIGNALS-MIB::oversightInteger.4.0 = Wrong Type (should 
be OCTET STRING): IpAddress: 127.0.0.1
GET-LATEST-SIGNALS-MIB::oversightInteger.5.0 = Wrong Type (should  
e OCTET STRING): Counter32: 42
GET-LATEST-SIGNALS-MIB::oversightInteger.6.0 = Wrong Type (should 
be OCTET STRING): Gauge32: 42
```

So now I wanted to change the value"Life, the Universe, and Everything" dynamically so how we can change the oid values dynamically?.

I'm stuck at this point for almost 2 weeks now so any help will be really appreciated!!

Comment: Start by simplifying your case statement: `case ${REQ#"$PLACE."} in [0-6]|2.[01]|...` and so on. `${REQ#"$PLACE."}` Removes the prefix, so only need to match numbers, `[23]` matches 2 or 3, `[0-6]` matches any number from 0 to 6. etc.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but you'd probably be far better of building a few `grep` regular expressions.

Comment: @dan basically overall I just want to change the values of the variables which are shown in the MIB browser dynamically.

Comment: @dan I'm running one application which will be reading GPS data. So this GPS data will keep changing right? so, I want to reflect that updated GPS data into the MIB browser.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the protocol you're using. Firstly, I would look for any existing tool that's specifically designed to parse and manipulate this data. Failing that, I might use `awk` for this, maybe even `sed`. You might need to explain your task more clearly and generically (eg. I want this output format, from this input format, with examples of both). That means that people who aren't familiar with this protocol can probably  still help you.

Comment: For example, piping your command through `awk '$1~/::oversightInteger\.1\.0$/ && $NF = "\"My String\""'` Will change the string. From their you could build the regex to match more numbers, (like `::oversightInteger\.[1-6]\.0$`) or add other regexes to print different strings.

Comment: To make the value of that specific OID object dynamic, you cannot hard code `"Life, the Universe, and Everything"` in the script. Instead, this value should be read from another source (like a text file) and then you can edit that source to modify the value on the fly.

Comment: @LexLi In our application, we were using the sqlite3 database to store the values of the variables. So can we read the database variables using shell script?

Comment: "Another source" of course can be a SQLite file, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643403/shell-scripting-sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve this issue I have included a `sqlite3 database`.

Now, whenever we will get the latest values in our `embedded c application` (which will be always running behind) we are updating the same in the database so in between if `SNMPD daemon` receives any request for example set, get etc then the script will go and read the database to get the latest values of the mib varialbes and will be sent to the mib browser.

We are using the following command in the script to get the data from the database

```
echo "$(sqlite3 /home/root/database/pdu.db <<'END_SQL'
.timeout 2000
SELECT Variable_Value FROM Data Where Sr_No='2';
END_SQL)
```